# Limit of the sequence $a_n=\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$a_n=\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$ where $b_1=1$, $b_2=1$ and $b_{n+2}=b_n+b_{n+1}$, $n=1, 2, 3,...$.

Find $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n$.

I can see that the sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is neither monotonically increasing nor monotonically decreasing.

Please anyone help me solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $a_n$ isn't monotonic. But $a_{2n}$, on the other hand, is. As is $a_{2n+1}$. But the easiest way to actually find that limit is to find a formula for $b_n$, and use that to find a formula for $a_n$.

Comment: [Golden Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Relationship_to_Fibonacci_sequence)

Comment: $b_{n}$ is Fibonacci sequence and limit of $a_{n}$ is the golden ration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, suppose the limit $l$ exist, then when $n$ is large, $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=\frac{b_n}{b_{n-1}}=l$, while $b_{n+1}=b_n+b_{n-1}$, so you have $\frac{b_n+b_{n-1}}{b_n}=\frac{b_n}{b_{n-1}}$, and so $1+\frac{1}{l}=l$, and so $l^2-l-1=0\, (l>0)$, and so you get $l$ is the golden ratio.

Answer (score 1):

We know that

$b_1=1$, $\;b_2=1\;$ and

$b_{n+2}=b_n+b_{n+1}\;,\;\;$ for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;.$

By dividing both sides by $\;b_{n+1}\;$ we get

$\frac{b_{n+2}}{b_{n+1}}=\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}+1\;,\;\;$ for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;.$

By letting $\;a_n=\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\;$ we get

$a_1=1$, $\;a_2=2\;$ and

$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{a_n}+1\;,\;\;$ for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;.$

Therefore

$a_{n+2}=\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}+1=\frac{a_n}{a_n+1}+1=\frac{2a_n+1}{a_n+1}\;,\;\;$ for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;.$

Moreover, given that $a_n>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, it results that

$a_{n+2}>a_n \iff \frac{2a_n+1}{a_n+1}>a_n \iff a_n<\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$,

$a_{n+2}<\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \iff \frac{2a_n+1}{a_n+1}<\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \iff a_n<\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} $

Since $\;a_1=1<\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\;a_2=2>\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, by applying repeatedly the previous equivalences, we get

$a_{2m-1}<a_{2m+1}<\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\;$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$,

$a_{2m}>a_{2m+2}>\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\;$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

So there exist

$\lim_\limits{m\to\infty} a_{2m-1}=\sup_\limits{m\in\mathbb{N}} \left\{a_{2m-1}\right\}=l_1\le\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and

$\lim_\limits{m\to\infty} a_{2m}=\inf_\limits{m\in\mathbb{N}} \left\{a_{2m}\right\}=l_2\ge\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}.$

Since

$a_{2m+1}=\frac{2a_{2m-1}+1}{a_{2m-1}+1}\;$ for all $\;m\in\mathbb{N}\;\;$ and

$a_{2m+2}=\frac{2a_{2m}+1}{a_{2m}+1}\;$ for all $\;m\in\mathbb{N}\;\;$,

as $\;m\to\infty\;$ it results that

$l_1=\frac{2l_1+1}{l_1+1}\;$ and $\;l_2=\frac{2l_2+1}{l_2+1}$.

So $\;l_1=l_2=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\;$ and there exists

$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} a_n=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.